# How do I make a middle item sandwiched between two others take up the remaining height of the parent in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent with 3 children placed vertically, top and bottom are wide (600x200) and middle is tall (200x600). The parent itself is much smaller (100x200) as my goal is to force the children to be constrained in the parent's size.

```
<div class="parent">
   <img class="wide" src="wide.png"></img>
   <img class="tall" src="tall.png"></img>
   <img class="wide" src="wide.png"></img>
</div>
```

The wide children are very easy to contain by setting their width to 100%, but the problem comes up when trying to make the middle child adhere to the **remaining** space.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) 20px
    );
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.wide {
    width: 100%;
}
.tall {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I have tried setting the middle item to 100% height or flex-grow 1 but this does not have the desired effect:

[image]
[image]

When height is set too 100% it fails to account for the size of the other two pieces, when flex-grow is set to 1 it appears to just be full size.

I tried a handful of other variations of this, but none resulted in what I actually wanted, which would be this:

[image]

I've of course also looked through all Stack Overflow posts resembling my issue but can't find one covering what I need.

Is what I'm describing possible? Surely it must be, I've just been running into this wall trying to figure out how. The height of the tall piece should end up being `100% - 2*(the height of the wide piece)` but of course the height of the wide pieces depends on how the piece is resized so knowing that value in advanced isn't an option. I also don't want to hardcode a value in like I did for the above screenshot because I plan to make the parent container capable of having a varying size.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't really understand, you don't know any height? I don't think you can do this when you don't know at least 2 heights from `parent`, `wide` and `tall`. If you set `width: 100%` and `flex: 1` to `tall` then it will take up all available space between `wide` but you have to define `height` for `wide`.

Comment: keep the flex-grow method and add min-height:0 to the element

Comment: @MilosStojanovic Indeed the only height that is known ahead of time would be the height of the parent. This is because I want the aspect ratios to remain as they are so the images don't end up distorted or cropped.

Comment: @TemaniAfif omg that was it! I can't believe it was that simple! Perhaps this is needed because it assumes its original size to be the minimum size by default? Either way thank you!
Edit: Could you pls post your response as an answer so I can mark yours as correct?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) 20px
    );
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflowing content */
}

.wide {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* Adjust height automatically */
    max-height: 50%; /* Maximum height is 50% of the parent */
}

.tall {
    width: auto; /* Adjust width automatically */
    height: auto; /* Adjust height automatically */
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-height: 100%; /* Maximum height to prevent overflow */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img class="wide" src="wide.png" alt="Wide Image Top">
   <img class="tall" src="tall.png" alt="Tall Image">
   <img class="wide" src="wide.png" alt="Wide Image Bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the same outcome as setting height to 110%, just that it crops it off once its beyond the parent's boundary. This makes it so the 3rd child on the bottom is completely hidden:  https://i.imgur.com/oXzBgGO.png 